# How to get median based on probability distribution?

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

From some calculation, I have a distribution of discrete data $(i,P_i)$ and then want to get the median based on this distribution. Naive way is to create a list

```
list = Table[Sum[p[[j]], {j, i}], {i, n}]
```

then find the first element greater than $0$:

```
pos = Position[list, _?(# >= 0.5 &)][[1, 1]]
```

but this way is pretty slow, especially when I have a very large amount of data. The reason is I have to do Sum everytime. I did several attempts to speed up, such as

```
list = Table[0, {i, n}]
For[i = 1, i <= n, i ++, list[[i]] = If[i == 1, p[[i]], list[[i - 1]] + p[[i]]]]
```

or even smarter by using Accumulate

```
Accumulate[p]
```

and then do same Position operation. This made everything much faster and I'm pretty happy with it. I'm wondering whether some similar function is already in Mathematica, so we don't have to manually implement this. However after lookup the Median, I have no results relate to this. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Have you seen `EmpiricalDistribution[]`?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on what J.M. hinted at, this is one way of achieving what you want with `EmpiricalDistribution`.

First let's get an example table of pairs of `{value,probability}` like you showed in your question

```
list = Transpose[{Range[10], #/Total[#] &[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]]}]
```

> {{1, 0.0538923}, {2, 0.00538521}, {3, 0.158895}, {4, 0.10697}, {5, 
>     0.0799713}, {6, 0.17624}, {7, 0.112601}, {8, 0.128191}, {9, 
>     0.156779}, {10, 0.0210756}}

Then we make this into a `EmpiricalDistribution`:

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[list[[All, 2]] -> list[[All, 1]]]
Plot[CDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 11}, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: CDF plot]

Here we use the syntax where we have used the probabilities as weights to single sample examples to get the right distribution. If you have your original data sample before binning that's even better as an input and `EmpiricalDistribution` will do the binning for you.

Now we can easily get the median by calling `Median` on our distribution:

```
Median[dist]
```

> 6

Comment: Thanks for following through. ;) One thing: you could have used `Normalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10], Total]` as well.

Comment: @J.M. Ah, cool idea! Just thought about `#/Norm[#,1]&`, but haven't thought about using Normalize in that way!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) as follows:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = Transpose[{Range[10], #/Total[#] &[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]]}];
wd = WeightedData @@ Transpose[list];
```

You can use [`Median`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Median.html) or [`Quantile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantile.html) with `wd`

```
Median[wd]
```

> 5

```
Quantile[wd, 1/2]
```

> 5

Alternatively,

```
Median[EmpiricalDistribution[wd]]
Quantile[EmpiricalDistribution[wd], 1/2]
InverseCDF[EmpiricalDistribution[wd], 1/2]
```

> 5

Answer (score 1):

If it is really about performance, here is some inspiration.

Some data...

```
n = 10000000;
i = Range[n];
SeedRandom[1];
p = Normalize[RandomReal[{0, 1}, n], Total];
```

Thies' solution (with timing):

```
Median@EmpiricalDistribution[p -> i] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.332, 4999860}

klgr's solution:

> {0.18, 4999860}

```
Median[WeightedData @@ {i, p}] // RepeatedTiming
```

Computing the CDF and using `Nearest` to determine the elements closed to `0.5`:

```
With[{P = Accumulate[p]},
 If[P[[#]] < 0.5, # + 1, #] &@Last@Nearest[P -> i, 0.5]
 ] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.046, 4999860}

Computing the CDF and using good ol' `BinarySearch` to determine the element closest to `0.5` (breaking ties in favor of the largest element below `0.5`):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
With[{P = Accumulate[p]},
 Ceiling@BinarySearch[P, 0.5]
 ] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.023, 4999860}

Using OP's idea in a `CompiledFunction` (breaking ties in favor of the largest element below `0.5`):

First compile

```
cf = Compile[{{p, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{P = 0., i = 0},
    While[P < 0.5, i++; P += Compile`GetElement[p, i];];
    i
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

and then compute

```
i[[cf[p]]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00568, 4999860}

Comment: I don't think that the method with `Nearest` always gives the correct value for the median with a discrete distribution.  Consider `i = Range[5]; p = {0.1, 0.39, 0.3, 0.01, 0.2}; Nearest[Accumulate[p] -> i, 0.5]`.  The result is `2` when the median is `3`.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the hint. I was in the wrong assumption that the median were defined as the element in the list with cummulated probability closest to `0.5`. Instead, we have to look for the smallest element with cummulated probability above to `0.5`, right? I fixed the code, also for the binary searches. I hope that it is correct now.

Comment: A median (rather than "the" median) for a univariate probability distribution is any value such that at least half the probability is below that value and at least half of the probability is above that value.  For some discrete distributions that could result in 2 possible values that satisfy that definition.